# NestJS Not Authenticated to read Github Files

Tags: github, nestjs

In a NestJS app, Im trying to download a file stored in github, but it seems the get request is returning a not authenticated type response.

`this.httpService.get('githubrepourl/raw/master/src/config/file.txt)`

Response:
`<h3 data-view-component="true" class="mb-1">You are being redirected to your identity provider in order to authenticate</h3>`

do you know how to configure the project to be authentificated in github and that im available to read the file from my NestJS app? Im finding internet information a bit messy.

I already tried to add my user and my token at the beginning of the url, but i got the same result.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url was wrong for reading github raw files

Comment: It's great that you found the answer, but you should make sure that you accept your (own) answer.